# SQL and NOT IN with NULLs

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, in-clause

I was actually trying some thing similar with a sub query, and couldn’t understand what was going wrong. I have managed to simplify the question to the following.

I have a simple table which may include a `NULL` in one of the columns:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;
CREATE TEMP TABLE data (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    number INT,
    string TEXT
);
INSERT INTO data(id,number,string)
VALUES (1,1,'Apple'),(2,1,'Accordion'),(3,2,'Banana'),(4,2,'Banjo'),(5,NULL,'Whatever');
SELECT * FROM data WHERE number IN(1,2,NULL);
SELECT * FROM data WHERE number NOT IN(1,2,NULL);
```

There is a live version at https://dbfiddle.uk/KhTzbX_E .

When I look for rows matching the `number` column:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data WHERE number IN(1,2,NULL);
```

I get a few results, as expected. This doesn’t include the row where `number` is `NULL`, but I suppose that the `IN` expression is short for `WHERE a = b`.

If I look for the non-matches:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data WHERE number NOT IN(1,2,NULL);
```

I get nothing at all.

I can’t see how that can be right. The expression `IN(1,2,NULL)` must return a valid list otherwise the first one wouldn’t work.

What is going on here, and is there a correct way to do this?

Note: I know it’s silly to put in the `NULL`, but the idea is that the list is supposed to be a sub query which might return a vew `NULL`s. I also know that I can filter out the `NULL`s in the sub query. However that looks like a workaround to me.

I have tried this in PostgreSQL, MariaDB and Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old trap for people who are not experienced with NULL: if a `NOT IN` list contains NULL, **the result set is always empty**.

To understand why, let's rewrite

```
WHERE number NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)
```

to the semantically equivalent

```
WHERE number <> 1 AND number <> 2 AND number <> NULL
```

Then note that `number <> NULL` will **always** return NULL. This is easiest to understand if you think of “NULL” as “unknown”: when asked if an unknown number is different from any given number, the answer could be “true” or “false”, depending on the unknown value of the unknown number. So the answer must be “unknown”, which is the `boolean` value NULL.

Now `something AND NULL` can be `FALSE` (if `something` is `FALSE`) or NULL (if `something` is NULL or `TRUE`), but it never can be `TRUE`. And a `WHERE` condition only passes rows where the condition is `TRUE`. Both `FALSE` and NULL won't pass.

Comment: Actually, I’m quite experienced with `NULL`. What I wasn’t aware of is how the expression is (virtually) expanded. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `NOT IN` is of very limited use if any `null` values are involved. This isn't exactly a new insight. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

```sql
nr NOT IN (1,2,NULL)
```

translates to:

```sql
NOT (nr = 1 OR nr = 2 or nr = null)
```

`nr = null` is always `null`, and since `false OR null` results in `null`, the expression can never become `true`. Used in the `WHERE` clause, such a filter can never return any rows.

Comment: I'd rather say _unexpected_ instead of _useless_. (It all depends on what result you want.)

Comment: @jarlh That's right, of course. I put "of limited use" now.

Answer (score 0):

Any equality check involving NULL will return null, and null does not equal null. Null needs special language using `is/is not`

My recommendation would be to add another part to your where clause to make it work, and also keep it readable:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (number NOT IN(1,2) and number is not null);
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (number IN (1,2)  or number is null);
```

Try playing around with null and you'll see how it behaves:

```
select case when null = null then 1 else 0 end as test
```

Answer (score 0):

`IN()` is a shortcut. `number IN(1,2,NULL)` equates to:

(number = 1 or number = 2 or number = NULL)

you cannot use equality against NULL you **must** use `IS NULL` instead, hence the IN shortcut won't work as you expected with with NULLs.

As you suggested, it is recommended that you strip out any NULLs if using a subquery.